# Failed to build docker images for angular application

Tags: angular, docker

I am trying to build docker image for my angular application but as per my code it failed. I am sharing the build logs below.

```
Status: Downloaded newer image for node:10-alpine
 ---> b328632eb00c
Step 42/66 : RUN mkdir -p app/mean-stack/angular-js/app
 ---> Running in ce1a7173abcb
Removing intermediate container ce1a7173abcb
 ---> 9e9e9b2f28ca
Step 43/66 : WORKDIR app/mean-stack/angular-js/app
 ---> Running in 94e5a1e7a60c
Removing intermediate container 94e5a1e7a60c
 ---> 967f4d0fb578
Step 44/66 : COPY package.json app/mean-stack/angular-js/app
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder831746110/package.json: no such file or directory
```

I am explaining my directory structure below.

```
-> project
     -> app
         -> mean-stack
             ->angular-js

   -> Dockerfile
```

So my directory structure is like above where inside `angular-js` folder I have all angular code. inside project folder the `Dockerfile` is present. I am explaining below my docker file code.

**Dockerfile:**

```
# Stage 1
FROM node:10-alpine as build-step
RUN mkdir -p app/mean-stack/angular-js/app
WORKDIR /app/mean-stack/angular-js/app
COPY package.json app/mean-stack/angular-js/app
RUN npm install
COPY . app/mean-stack/angular-js/app
RUN npm run build --prod

#stage 2
FROM nginx:1.17.1-alpine
RUN rm -r /usr/share/nginx/html/*
COPY app/mean-stack/angular-js/dist/ubot /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 8090
```

Here I need to build the docker image for Angular app but its failing in middle while building. Can anybody help me to resolve this issue and build the image successfully ?

Comment: Please see if your package.json inside app or angular-js folder.

Comment: @HPsing `package.json` inside `angular-js` folder.

Comment: So I think keep your working directory angular-js. I can see you are copying package.json from "app/mean-stack/angular-js/app" path, but it is inside "app/mean-stack/angular-js" it.

Comment: Ok I am building again after doing changes as per you.

Comment: @HPSingh: I did the changes like `COPY /app/mean-stack/angular-js/package.json /app/mean-stack/angular-js/app` but this time I am getting some other build error. `The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 1`.

Comment: You need to explicitly install node / npm in your container before running npm install.